# Looking for other dual booting options

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am upgrading my fathers computer that has Ubuntu on it, however he wants to keep Ubuntu as an operating system, I heard of dual boot and thought it would be worth a try, however I can't back up the data because most of it is password protected and he forgets his password. Is there any way I could try and add windows 7 onto the Ubuntu desktop without having to take Ubuntu off first, or deleting all the information on the computer if I put windows 7 and it then takes priority. I'm not sure how much of that made sense, but if anyone knows another method of dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In ANY case, you need to create a backup of all the data. Work with your father to backup everything that's important. If you can't use another harddrive and move over his data later. For installing Windows on a machine that already has Ubuntu on it, see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: My understanding is that if you want a dual boot you have to have windows on it first and then put Ubuntu on after. If you go the other way (your situation) it could clear down the older os. Also if your dad has lost the passwords is it worth trying to save the old os? You always have the option of backing up the user folder and then adding it to the clean Ubuntu install. Or at least this way you will keep all the files for a later investigation.

Comment: Is it the login password, which you can recover or does he have full encryption which without password you will not be able to recover. Either way you always should have a good backup procedure. You can install Windows after Ubuntu if drive is MBR(msdos) and you have a primary partition left. Windows only boots from a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag.

Answer (score 1):

Use gparted to shrink Ubuntu partition and make enough unallocated space for windows. Insert Windows installation DVD or USB. Power on the PC and bring BIOS menu to boot into Windows installer. During installation go to advanced option, create new primary drive in unallocated space and install Windows in that drive. Be careful to not touch the Ubuntu drive. Proceed with installation. After installation is complete you have both Windows and Ubuntu on your PC. To switch between them you have to shutdown the PC. Then power it on and bring the BIOS menu. Then change the boot order. That's it.